# FAILED Plug-in 'dev' is already in use in IBM Cloud CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud

Im trying install plugins for my ibmcloud repository on Ubuntu. When I run the code: `ibmcloud plugin install dev` I get the following

> Installing binary... FAILED Plug-in 'dev' is already in use in IBM Cloud CLI.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried ignoring it? Its just saying it's already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *dev* plug-in has been bundled inside of the IBM Cloud CLI since version `1.0.0` released in the spring of 2020:
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/whats-new-in-ibm-cloud-cli-version-1-0-0

It sounds as though you are on this release of the CLI or higher and that is why the *dev* plug-in can't be installed, because it is actually already there. If you type `ibmcloud dev` you should get the command list for the plug-in.

At this time, the *dev* plug-in is still available from the CLI plug-in repo to support users who have not yet moved up to IBM Cloud CLI `1.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the installed IBM Cloud CLI plugins with

```
ibmcloud plugin list
```

To see all the available plugins with `installed` and `not installed` status,

```
ibmcloud plugin repo-plugins
```

To update all the plugins,

```
ibmcloud plugin update
```

Comment: This is true for plug-ins that are not bundled inside IBM Cloud CLI itself. But commands such as dev and sl that are actually included in the binary do not show in the plugin list at this time, FYI.